# What type of pin in this (see picture)? I see them in FSRs but they don't appear to be Dupont connectors

Tags: connector, identification, pins, fsr

Here are the images of the pins:

[image: side1] [image: side2]

And [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MP4RL9Q) is the FSR that it came from:

[image: fsr]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be some form of pins used in [clincher connectors](https://www.google.com/search?q=clincher%20connector&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjA0bukxpvmAhVB16QKHXcpD3gQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=clincher%20connector&gs_l=img.3..35i39l2j0i5i30i19l2.119793.119793..119967...0.0..0.60.60.1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.fHZlenZu4Hg&ei=vmrnXcD6NMGukwX30rzABw&bih=937&biw=1920)

Comment: After searching endlessly for types of clincher connectors, I can't seem to find what the specific pins are called or where I can buy them without the blue casing. I might ask for more information in a separate question later.

Answer (score 0):

I now see that FSRs all appear to be made by Interlink, so it's likely that these pins are for their specific purpose and don't have a name. However, like David mentioned, clincher connectors seem to be the closest thing to them.